# Gauss's Law and Flux through Sphere vs. Shell

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I'm having trouble understanding Gauss's law.

Suppose you have a sphere centered upon a positive charge. Then the flux through the sphere is some positive value, according to Gauss's law. I try to analogize the positive charge as this 3D source of water and the surface of the sphere is this boundary line. Since there is a net flow of water out of the sphere's boundary, the flux must be positive.

But for the case of a neutral, non-conducting shell centered upon a positive charge, wouldn't the flux be zero? Using the analogy, any water entering from the inner boundary of the shell also exits through the outer boundary, so there is no net flow of water. But Gauss's law states that *any* closed surface (including this shell) can be used to calculate flux, so it must be positive.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, this might be helpful.

Gauss's Law refers to the *net* flux through a closed surface.  If the surface doesn't include any sources or sinks, then it is true that the net flux will be zero.

In the case you describe, the flux through the shell will be zero if you draw a closed surface that includes the inner boundary and outer boundary but not the charge at the center.  However, having a zero flux doesn't mean that the electric field is zero on the surface of the closed surface.  It means that the electric field points in the same direction as the surface normal on one side of the boundary and in the opposite direction as the surface normal on the other side, thus adding to zero net flux through the surface.

The below figure shows the arrangement:

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand: so technically the shell does not enclose the charge because the charge is not physically within the volume of the shell, so it is correct that the flux is zero. On the other hand, the volume of the sphere does include the charge inside of it, so is is correct that the flux is positive.

Is this correct?